# Error estimation, parameter estimation

Tags: parameter-estimation

I have some problems with the error estimation of a frequency response measurement. The measured transfer function $H$ has to be fitted to a model $$H=A+i\omega B,$$ where $A$ and $B$ are the unknowns and $\omega=2\pi f$ ($\omega$=angular frequency).

In the model, $A$ represents a stiffness and $B$ represents a damper. With the error estimate of the real part I am satisfied so far. I generate the data representing the measurement in this example with the following Matlab code:

```
clear
close all
f=linspace(0,400,50);
B=0.001; % B= constant
err=rand(32,50); % random numbers between 0 and 1 
Im=B*2*pi*f+err; % Some sample
figure(1)% plot imaginary part over frequency to show standard deviation 
errorbar(f,mean(Im),std(Im)) 
xlabel('f in Hz')
ylabel('Imaginary part')
```

A typical measurement of the imaginary part looks as followed:[image: ![Typical imaginary part]

At each frequency, the standard deviation is almost the same. There is a positive offset. The real measurements may also have negative offsets. To determine $B$ (i.e. the damper), I divide the imaginary part by $\omega$:

```
% Estimate B
figure(2) 
errorbar(f,mean(Im)./(2*pi*f),std(Im)./(2*pi*f)) % 
xlabel('f in Hz')
ylabel('B')
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

From a mathematical point of view, the result is obvious, but if the slope in figure (1) represents the damping constant, how should we interpret the change in the standard deviation?

---

As mentioned earlier, there is an offset in the measurement that causes $B$ to increase in this example, see figure(2). Does anyone have any ideas on how to eliminate the offset? There are some additional conditions. In the example above, $B$ is constant. Unfortunately, in the real measurement, $B$ is itself a function of $f$.

Comment: In your example code you are using rand(), which has a non-zero mean. If you would use randn() instead then this should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first of all take the low energy approach and just correct for the offset:

```
figure(1)% plot imaginary part over frequency to show standard deviation 
errorbar(f,mean(Im-mean(Im(:,1))),std(Im)) 
xlabel('f in Hz')
ylabel('Imaginary part')
```

which gives

[image: Offset-corrected version of figure 1]

and then the estimate seems better using

```
figure(2) 
errorbar(f,mean(Im-mean(Im(:,1)))./(2*pi*f),std(Im)./(2*pi*f)) % 
hold on;
plot([0 400], [B B])
xlabel('f in Hz')
ylabel('B')
```

showing

[image: Redo of Figure 2 using the offset correction.]

where I've overlaid the true value of $B$ on the plot.

**NOTE:** There is much more that could be done to improve this, but I'd take the simple approach first.